# Android Xamarin:C# library development

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I am very new to Android development,I like to develop a library using c# and use the library in Android device application. I got some idea to use Xamarin studio, the library generated was a dll. Am I going in a right path? Please guide me for library development.

Comment: I actually been in contact back in April with the Xamarin Support team and they told me that it's not possible to create libraries with their product.

Comment: This is not true.  You can create libraries (dll) with Xamarin and reuse them in other Xamarin projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a Android library project and re-use it in multiple Xamarin Android projects.